# What are these spots/streaks on my tomato leaves?

Tags: leaves, tomatoes

I recently transplanted these outside to my garden and the spots/streaks started up. This was about 2 days ago. I did acclimate them to the sun and the outdoors so I'm not sure what's causing this. Is it dangerous or natural, and also what is causing it?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tomatoes are not grown for their aesthetics. Nothing looks wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

When you water your tomato plants, try not to get the leaves wet. Fuzzy-leaves plants like tomatoes have hairs on the leaves that will catch and hold droplets of water. The droplets can focus the sunlight (like a magnifying glass) and cause leaf damage.

I can't say for certain that's your issue, but it would be consistent with the size of the damaged spots.